# Problems with Unity Random Function

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, random, void

Good evening, I was working on a graphic adventure and I want to make a random function with a 4 digit code, turns out that as I am a very novice programmer, I crashed with an inconvenient

```
private void CheckResults()
{
    if (codeSequence = RandomCode.RanCode.ToString())
        {
    SoundManager.PlaySound("nice");
    }

else
{
    SoundManager.PlaySound("wrong");
}
```

**"RandomCode.RanCode"** is a int void, and adding **"ToString"** will shot an error saying

**"RanCode is a method which is not valid in the given context"**

This is the RandomCode void:

```
 public void RanCode()
{
    Code = Random.Range(1111, 9999);
}
```

If anyone out there has any ideas or solves, I will be eternally grateful

Comment: What is an `int void`? Your method returns `void` no `int` at all. Your are using `=` that is an assignment where it should probably be `==`. You are using "method.ToString" .. what you probably wanted to do is return an `int` and then do `RanCode().To string()` in order to execute the method and use `ToString` on the result, not the method itself ....

Comment: What do you mean by "I crashed with an inconvenient?"

Comment: Be sure to include all important information for the problem you are having.  For instance: what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the downvotes.  stackoverflow can be very harsh to new people.  Just search on Google on how to post questions and as you learn you will receive less down votes.  Unfortunately few stackoverflow down-voters will explain why they down-voted so you just kind of have to figure it out.  Also, if you can, have someone you know review your question before you send it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as an "int void". A method either returns nothing (`void`) or returns a value (in your case you seem to expect `int`).

```
//   Returns nothing
//      |
//      v
public void RanCode()
{
    // assigns result of `Range` to `Code` property/field
    Code = Random.Range(1111, 9999);
}
```

If you want to also return the value, you need to rewrite your method like this:

```
public int RanCode()
{
    Code = Random.Range(1111, 9999);
    return Code;
}
```

You do have another issue here:

```
RandomCode.RanCode.ToString()
```

To call a method you need `()`, so it should be this:

```
RandomCode.RanCode().ToString()
```

Also, for equality checks you want `==` not `=` (which is assignment).

I do wonder why you're assigning a value to `Code` here. If we use your existing code (without my fix above), I guess that perhaps you intended something like this instead?:

```cs
private void CheckResults()
{
    RandomCode.RanCode();   
    if (codeSequence == RandomCode.Code.ToString())
    {
        SoundManager.PlaySound("nice");
    }
    else
    {
        SoundManager.PlaySound("wrong");
    }   
}
```

Comment: You probably rather want to use `==` for your `if` condition and not an assignment ;) And move the `}` that closes the method after the `else` block` ^^

Comment: @derHugo Doh. I miscounted their `}`s and didn't spot the `=`. Thanks! :)